# angular conditional operator: execute multiple statement

Tags: html, angular

Here is the logic: On enter, execute the following if statement

```
if (!elementB.isOpen){
    elementB.open()
else {
    elementC.open()
    elementC.focus()
    elementB.close()
}
```

I want to use the ? conditional operator and add it after (keyup.enter):

```
<mat-form-field (keyup.enter)="!elementB.isOpen ? elementB.open() : elementC.open();elementC.focus();elementB.close()">
```

However the code above gave me an error. It seems like I cannot execute multiple lines of code with `conditional operator( ? : )`.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Well you can, separating each statement by a `**,**`. But it's not really recommended. You should keep more of your logic in TypeScript. It's more managable and unit-testable that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to give `else` in a method,so that you can simplify the  logic

```
<mat-form-field (keyup.enter)="!elementB.isOpen ? elementB.open() : changeElement(elementC,elementB)">

  changeElement(elementC: any, elemenB: any) :void {
        elementC.open();
        elementC.focus();
        elementB.close();
    }
```

Comment: elementB and elementC are ids of mat-select, like: <mat-select placeholder="Contact" [formControl]="contact" #elementB>. How can I access them in my.component.ts and apply functions like open(), focus()...

Comment: add elements as parameters in changeElement(elementC,elementB)

Answer (score 3):

Use the component file rather than stuffing the template full of logic:

```
<mat-form-field (keyup.enter)="elementActions()">
```

In your component:

```
public elementActions(): void {
  if (!this.elementB.isOpen) {
    elementB.open();
  } else {
    this.elementC.open();
    this.elementC.focus();
    this.elementB.close();
  }
}
```

I know it's terribly mundane, but that's what the component.ts file should really be used for.

Comment: elementB and elementC are ids of mat-select, like: <mat-select placeholder="Contact" [formControl]="contact" #elementB>. How can I access them in my.component.ts and apply functions like open(), focus()...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it around brackets

```
<mat-form-field (keyup.enter)="!elementB.isOpen ? (elementB.open()) : (elementC.open(),elementC.focus(),elementB.close())">
```

Comment: , is not working: Parser Error: Unexpected token ','